# Prevent 'reply all' in Facebook group message

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I'm the admin for a Facebook group of approximately 50 members, and I want to send a single message to everyone in the group. I need to use a message because most members of the group do not receive notifications for posts on the group page.

The last time I sent a message to the whole group, a few members started replying in a casual chatty way that spammed all of the other members and led to some of them leaving the group.

Is it possible to send a message to a group that does not allow anyone to "reply all"?

Comment: I closed this question because it's +7 years old, it had been bumped 36 times, and have not attracted activity. Apparently, it is not interesting/helpful enough for this community to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely apologize for the confusion, I'm not sure how I misunderstood the question so badly.

However, after the fact, I exhausted as many resources as I could possibly find regarding the (correct) topic. Including dozens of "Open" and "Closed" Facebook tickets, with literally thousands of people buzzing in the forums about this exact issue, all to no avail.

I enjoy finding solutions to odd/difficult issues; but I have to be honest and say that I'm beginning to think that there really is just no way to do such a thing anymore. According to Facebook Help, the feature was actually **removed** recently, which has people very angry with Facebook.

It seems to be very well documented, and I did not find a single piece of information that led me to believe otherwise - including analyzing a huge amount of CSS and Developer console entries in an attempt to prove them wrong.

But with that being said - I have one last suggestion. If you are very desperate to actually get this accomplished, I highly recommend you try one of the following two things:

- Automate the process: There is a program that is called "iMacros". There are several different automation options based on your need. This would be the very best (if not only other) option for someone who maintains a group of ~100+ individuals.  Additionally, I was astounded by the sheer volume of YouTube tutorials on the subject of using the program to complete similar, if not identical, tasks.  I got the program and tested it briefly and it really was quite easy with the guidance provided.
- The second option would be quite time consuming if you had a lot of contacts, but if you have a minimal amount, you could honestly just go into MESSAGES and select each member by doing some rapid insertion such as:

Go to "TO" field, and hit "A" followed by "Enter/Return" - and continue to do that until you have exhausted your "A" contacts - so on and so fourth until you reach the end or the limit - whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a post on your group page. But turn off commenting. They won’t be able to reply to that post them.
Also tag everyone as well on it at the top. Get them to like it. Which is important to that the ones that don’t answer you can for a second put commenting back on tag the ones in the comment and turn commenting back on. Do that till all have liked it.